# Rename all files to with four-digit padding, sort by the number values in the filename. bash

Tags: image, bash, sorting, unix, batch-rename

In other words, The file with the lowest index should map to 0001.jpg, and the second lowest index should map to 0002.jpg. Something like this:

```
DSCN-1009.JPG --> 1009.JPG
DSCN-1010.JPG --> 1010.JPG
DSCN-101.JPG --> 0101.JPG
DSCN-102.JPG --> 0102.JPG
```

or

```
DSCN-1.JPG --> 0001.JPG
DSCN-2.JPG --> 0002.JPG
DSCN-3.JPG --> 0003.JPG
DSCN-4.JPG --> 0004.JPG
```

I have this code that renames all files with four-digit padding.

```
X=1;
for i in *; do                       
  mv "$i" "$(printf %04d.%s "${X%.*}" "${i##*.}")"                      
  let X="$X+1"
done
```

but sorting of the files is off as it outputs like this (this is not what I want):

```
DSCN-1009.JPG --> 0009.JPG
DSCN-1010.JPG --> 0010.JPG
DSCN-101.JPG --> 0011.JPG
DSCN-102.JPG --> 0012.JPG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on your script but just changing how the numbers are computed:

```
for i in *
do
    mv "$i" "$(printf %04d.%s "${i//[^0-9]/}" "${i##*.}")"
done
```

The key is the bash construct `${i//[^0-9]/}`.  This removes all non-numbers from the filename.  So, if `i=DSCN-101.JPG`, then `${i//[^0-9]/}` becomes just `101`.  The `printf` command formats the number zero-padded to four digits.

`${i//[^0-9]/}` is called pattern substitution.  In its general form, it looks like `${parameter//pattern/string}` where `parameter` is the variable name.  `pattern` is some regular expression.  Everywhere that the regular expression `pattern` occurs in `variable`, it is replaced by `string`.  In our case, the regular expression is `[^0-9]` which matches all non-numbers and `string` is the empty string.  Thus, all non-numbers are replaced with the empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just in the middle of researching your answer, but then you gave a very good explanation. :)